# Which files store jmeter cache and cookies?

Tags: file, caching, cookies, jmeter

I have cookie and cache manager in my test plan. For some reason my jmeter script has been using the same session ID for over a week while manual testing in a browser a new session id is given every time a user logs in.

This session value I am given is not in my test plan in any parameters I am requesting. This value must be stored somewhere. I can see the cookie session it changes with every log in but not my session id.

Does anyone know how I may track down this value in my folders so I know whether it is my cache or cookies that is storing it.

I have tried astrogrep and other text string search tools and came up with nothing.

Any advice/guidance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for the way to store cookies as JMeter Variables you can add `CookieManager.save.cookies=true` line to *user.properties* file (it lives under /bin folder of your JMeter installation)

JMeter restart is required to pick up this property.

Once set it'll store all the cookies as JMeter Variables prefixed with `COOKIE_`. I.e. if you have cookie `SESSIONID` you will be able to refer it as `${COOKIE_SESSIONID}` where required.

You can additionally configure JMeter to save cookies in .jtl results file. To do so add the next line to *user.properties* file:

```
sample_variables=COOKIE_SESSIONID
```

Again JMeter restart is required.

If you look into .jtl results file you'll see SESSIONID cookie value in the last column. It'll allow you to track user sessions during results analysis.

The values can also be passed as command-line arguments instead of editing user.properties file as

```
jmeter -JCookieManager.save.cookies=true -Jsample_variables=COOKIE_SESSIONID -n -t /path/to/testplan.jmx -l /path/to/testresults.jtl
```

For HTTP Cache Manager it is not possible to store cache entries in results file as their structure is rather complex. However you can enable debug logging on the Cache Manager as follows:

```
jmeter -Ljmeter.protocol.http.control.CacheManager=DEBUG
```

So you'll be able to see output like:

```
2015/01/14 12:57:16 DEBUG - jmeter.protocol.http.control.CacheManager: GET(OAH) http://google.com/ null 
2015/01/14 12:57:16 DEBUG - jmeter.protocol.http.control.CacheManager: inCache http://google.com/ null 
2015/01/14 12:57:16 DEBUG - jmeter.protocol.http.control.CacheManager: GET(OAH) http://www.google.by/?gws_rd=cr&ei=fD22VJarBovXygO57IDoCg null 
2015/01/14 12:57:16 DEBUG - jmeter.protocol.http.control.CacheManager: inCache http://www.google.by/?gws_rd=cr&ei=fD22VJarBovXygO57IDoCg null 
2015/01/14 12:57:16 DEBUG - jmeter.protocol.http.control.CacheManager: setCache(null,private, max-age=0,-1,null,http://www.google.by/?gws_rd=cr&ei=fD22VJarBovXygO57IDoCg,Wed, 14 Jan 2015 09:57:16 GMT)
```

References:

- [HTTP Cookie Manager User Manual Entry](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](http://blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)

Comment: Thanks for the thorough response, I will give it a try.